# Azure Storage: Uploading image on azure storage getting successful but creating folder instead of Image

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-blob-storage, angular8

[image: Azure storage screenshot of my accout] I have used this [angular azure blob service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-azure-blob-service) for uploading blob (image) on azure storage.
This is uploading image successfully on azure storage but if we look into the azure account there is a folder created with the selected image name instead of the actual image.

```
upload() {
    if (this.currentFile !== null) {
        const baseUrl = this.blob.generateBlobUrl(
            this.Config,
            this.currentFile.name
        );
        console.log(baseUrl);

        this.config = {
            baseUrl: baseUrl,
            sasToken: this.Config.sas,
            blockSize:
                this.currentFile.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32
                    ? 1024 * 1024 * 4
                    : 1024 * 512, // OPTIONAL, default value is 1024 * 32
            file: this.currentFile,
            complete: () => {
                console.log("Transfer completed !");
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log("Error:", err);
            },
            progress: percent => {
                console.log("Transfer completed =", percent);
                // this.percent = percent;
            }
        };
        console.log(this.config);

        this.blob.upload(this.config);
    }
}
```

This is the upload function responsible for upload the image. Please let me know what is wrong here.
I am using this with angular 8.

This is the [Github link](https://github.com/Gullfaxi171/angular-azure-blob-service/tree/master/src/app) for the NPM source code.

Following is my config objct containing SAS token details:
   `Config: UploadParams = {
        sas:
            "https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-04-13T22:29:27Z&st=2020-04-13T14:29:27Z&spr=https,http&sig=PBJ62e8SU5%2FAef5Npmun5nvzZanb5UbVXqhJ17U1bGE%3D",
        storageAccount: "demo",
        containerName: "demo-images"
    }`

Comment: What is the value of `baseUrl` and what rights does the SAS token have?

Comment: there are no folders in blob storage. So could it just be that it is indeed your file - just missing the extension?

Comment: This should be you dont give the full name of the blob.

Comment: Hi, Any update?

Comment: Did you mean you upload file success but it's 0kb.

Comment: baseUrl is the combination of the file name and config object. Which will be the path of the folder on azure storage.

Comment: @silent There is a folder in blob storage, it is creating a new one inside that already exists one.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I'm giving full name if the blob, like this.currentFile.name, I also logged the base URL so it's an exact URL to the container folder with image name.

Comment: @VikasPalve, no, there are NO folders in azure blob storage. Anything that appears like a folder is only part of a blobs complete name. It might be displayed virtually as a folder. Thus, you also can never have an empty folder in blob

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yes, but instead of creating an image file it creating an empty folder with the selected file name. Also binding extra string to the extension. Like If I am uploading download.jpg then it will creating like https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/demo-images/download.jpghttps:/

Comment: @silent Actually it's not a folder, but its a container name, Do I need to create a folder inside the container?

Comment: @silent I have added a screenshot for your reference please have look at it.

Comment: Did you write the wrong image name or your file name is indeed `download.jpghttps:`?

Comment: @GeorgeChen...The issue is with the blob name :).

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri, I guess it's blob name problem however I test with nodejs sdk the blob name is allowed. Angular sdk problem?

Comment: Provided an answer. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri As you mentioned the name in the answer, That is what exactly I am getting as baseUrl `https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/demo-images/download.jpg` but once uploaded and copied it from Azure its giving the name with trailing (  https:/ ). Don't know why?

Comment: What does your SAS Token look like? Can you edit your question and include `this.Config` value? Obviously obfuscate the account name.

Comment: @GauravMantri Question is updated. Please have a look. Added config object.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the config object. I have updated my answer. Essentially you just have to use SAS token and not the SAS URL in your `sas` parameter.

Comment: @GauravMantri It's working now, thanks for your valuable time and efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the name of the blob. Assuming you copied the blob name correctly in one of the comments, it is coming up as:

```
https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/demo-images/download.jpghttps:/
```

If you notice, there is a trailing slash (`/`) in your blob name and because of this the portal UI (or for that matter any other Storage Explorer UI) will treat this as a virtual folder and hence you're seeing this as a folder.

Please check your code again specifically how you're setting the name of the blob. It should be `https://demo.blob.core.windows.net/demo-images/download.jpg`.

**UPDATE**

As I suspected, there's an issue with the `sas` parameter in your config object. You're passing SAS URL instead of SAS Token. Please change your `sas` parameter to something like:

```
?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-04-13T22:29:27Z&st=2020-04-13T14:29:27Z&spr=https,http&sig=PBJ62e8SU5%2FAef5Npmun5nvzZanb5UbVXqhJ17U1bGE%3D
```